# "reset" functionality in Windows SteadyState

Tags: windows, testing, imaging

I am running some upgrade testing on a computer with Windows SteadyState.

The workflow is "upgrade, write down results, reset to default condition".

However, I can't seem to dig up a button that says, "Reset Windows Now!", which would be handy.

Is there such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only way to revert back to the original system state in steady state is to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to script this with something like this (setting CurrentMode to WDP_MODE_DISCARD), but AFAIK you would then also have to reboot:

```
set objWbemServices = GetObject ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\wmi")
set setWdpObjects   = objWbemServices.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM WDP_Control")

for each objWdp in setWdpObjects
   objWdp.CurrentMode  = WDP_MODE_DISCARD
   objWdp.Put
next
```

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938335).